# Blockchain synchronization starting from scratch after switching between main network and testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization, fast-sync

I first synchronized the main blockchain via the CLI `geth --fast --cache=512`, it took several days to download around 3,300,000 blocks.

Then I closed the command line `geth`, opened Mist, and switched to testnet. The testnet blockchain was completely downloaded in a few hours, I started to mine and reached around 800 ETH on the testnet in one night.

Then I re-switched to the main network in Mist and all of sudden, the synchronization started back from scratch.

I checked the `%appdata%/Ethereum/geth/chaindata` folder, and it still contains around 13Gb of data, but Mist doesn't seem to care, it resynchronizes everything as if the folder was empty ...

Same thing happened when I switched another time to testnet : `%appdata%/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata` is full but in Mist, my mined ETH are gone and the synchronization starts from scratch.

Did I do anything wrong, or does it mean that :

1. One cannot use both testnet and main network ?
2. One cannot synchronize the blockchain first via the `geth` CLI and then via Mist user interface without having to start over?

Cheers

Comment: I would double check to confirm whether Mist is using the same datadir as that of your original geth client?

Comment: It seems so, as downloading the blockchain both with CLI geth and Mist, increases the number of files in the same directory.